# Prove the union of uncountably many closed intervals is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Problem

> $\{I_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A}$ are closed intervals with positive length, prove $E=\cup_{\alpha\in A}I_\alpha$ is measurable.

Since $E$ can be written as $(\cup_{\alpha\in A}I_\alpha^\circ)\cup(\cup_{\alpha\in A}\partial I_\alpha\setminus\cup_{\alpha\in A}I_\alpha^\circ)$ and $\cup_{\alpha\in A}I_\alpha^\circ$ is measurable, it suffices to show $\cup_{\alpha\in A}\partial I_\alpha\setminus\cup_{\alpha\in A}I_\alpha^\circ$ is measurable. My intuition is that $\cup_{\alpha\in A}\partial I_\alpha\setminus\cup_{\alpha\in A}I_\alpha^\circ$ is just the union of countably many points and is therefore measurable, but I don't know how to prove this.

Comment: What is a-circle?

Comment: You mean measurable in Borel?

Comment: @ Michael Interior.

Comment: @ Davi Measurable in $\mathbb{R}$, I think, i.e. $\forall A\subset\mathbb{R}, m^*(A)=m^*(A\cap E)+m^*(A\cap E^c)$.

Comment: One proof sketch: 

Define a relation $\sim$ on $A$ as $\alpha \sim \beta \iff I_\alpha \cap I_\beta \neq \emptyset,$ then the transitive closure of $\sim$ is an equivalence relation with at most countably many equivalence classes, and it's easy to show then that $\bigcup_{\alpha \in E} I_\alpha$ is an interval whenever $E\subset A$ is an equivalence class.

Comment: What is meant by the interior $\alpha^\circ$ of a subscript $\alpha$? For example if $\alpha =2$, what is the interior of 2? If $\alpha=green$ what is the interior of $green$?

Comment: @ Michael $I_\alpha^\circ$ is the interior of $I_\alpha$. For example, if $I_\alpha=[a,b], I_\alpha^\circ=(a,b)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to show that
$$\cup_{\alpha\in A}\partial I_\alpha\setminus\cup_{\alpha\in A}I_\alpha^\circ$$
is a countable set. If we call that set $S$, then $S=L\cup R$ where $L$ is the set of all points $x$ such that $x$ is the left endpoint of some $I_\alpha$ but $x$ is not in the interior of any $I_\alpha$, and $R$ is defined similarly but with "right" instead of "left".

To see that $L$ is countable, define a mapping $f:L\to\mathbb Q$ so that, for $x\in L$, $f(x)$ is some rational number $q\gt x$ such that $[x,q]$ is contained in some $I_\alpha$. Observe that $f$ is injective. Since $\mathbb Q$ is countable, this shows that $L$ is countable.

The proof that $R$ is countable is similar.

Therefore $\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}I_\alpha$ is the union of an open set and a countable set, so it's an $F_\sigma$ set.

In fact it can be shown that $\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}I_\alpha=\bigcup_{\alpha\in B}I_\alpha$ for some countable set $B\subseteq A$. Namely, for each point $x\in S$ choose some $I_\alpha$ having $x$ as an endpoint; and for each interval with rational endpoints which is covered by some $I_\alpha$, choose some $I_\alpha$ which covers it.

Comment: What is "in some fixed enumeration" and why is $f$ injective?

Comment: Since the set $\mathbb Q$ of rational numbers is countable, the rational numbers can be enumerated in a sequence $\mathbb Q=\{q_0,q_1,\dots\}$. Choosing the first rational number in this enumeration means choosing the one with least index. There is no reason for this except to avoid using the axiom of choice for this step. This is of no importance, and since it is causing confusion I took it out of the proof.

Comment: Why is $f$ injective? Assume for a contradiction that there are two distinct points $x,y\in L$ such that $f(x)=f(y)=q$. Without loss of generality we can assume that $x\lt y$. Then $x\lt y\lt q$ and $[x,q]\subseteq I_\alpha$ for some $\alpha\in A$. But then $y$ is an interior point of $I_\alpha$, contradicting the fact that $y\in S$.